# nginx conditional rewrite based on subdomains

Tags: nginx, rewrite, subdomain

I have the current nginx config that changes all subdomain requests to a specific pattern (`foo.example.com` -> `www.example.com/co/home/foo`):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/examplecom_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/examplecom.key;

    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.example\.com$;
    return 301 https://www.example.com/co/home/$subdomain$request_uri;
}
```

I need to add additional logic to redirect specific subdomains to a different URL (`bar.example.com` -> `www.example.com/co/bar`). In my mind, it looks something like:

```
server_name ~^(?<othersubdomain>(bar|baz))\.example\.com$;
return 301 https://www.example.com/co/$othersubdomain$request_uri;
```

Any suggestions for how I combine this all to get it working?

Comment: Use separate server block

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @alexey-ten's comment, the following worked:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/examplecom_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/examplecom.key;

    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>(bar|baz))\.example\.com$;
    return 301 https://www.example.com/co/$subdomain$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/examplecom_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/examplecom.key;

    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.example\.com$;
    return 301 https://www.example.com/co/home/$subdomain$request_uri;
}
```